# How hard it is to switch for a new Master's degree from different Undergraduate background?

Tags: masters, data, stem, consulting

For Non-STEM backgrounds like Media/Film Studies, is it possible to get a master's degree in Data Analytics/ Data science to go for the desired field? I feel extremely need for a transition into a data analyst role with strong scientific research methodologies, computational and quantitative skills. As I am looking forward to working within my expected environment, I have a strong dedication to this field. Currently, I am working independently on different projects using data and coding, some sort of skills of math(linear algebra, probability, matrix) and statistics (as classical inferences, Bayesian, Regression, Hypothesis Testing, ANOVA). But after all, I want to learn more critical and overwhelming concepts of computational processes, statistical methods and . I have an affinity for Technology and IoT very much.

Comment: What country are you looking to do your Master's in? Are you looking to do this at a top university?

Comment: I am technically looking for opportunities in the USA but not at a top university. Rather I would love to choose mid-ranges. Can I have any suggestions/advice about this?

Comment: What specifically? I know a lot about Master's degrees in the UK, but not so much about the US. Does Brian Tompsett's answer clear things up a bit?

Answer (score 4):

Some universities offer Master's degrees designed for students who are changing discipline; they are called *conversion* Master's. These are offered alongside a Master's degree for students who are coming from the same subject area; these are considered an *advanced* Master's.

In either case there will be some kind of admission qualification to achieve so that applicants need to demonstrate they have some of the qualities necessary to succeed. If you are admitted it will because of the potential demonstrated in your application. For example, mathematical and statistical experience together with using data and coding in a non-academic context would be that kind of appropriate background.

However such conversion Master's degrees are not a walk in the park as they compress several years of undergraduate study into a few intense trimesters.

I know this because I teach on one.

Answer (score 0):

Some universities allow this provided you have real good GPA in BS. But you will need to take some bachelor course in new discipline as pre-requisite.

Comment: Just to clarify, what does BS stand for here?

Comment: Bachelor of Science